# Error on jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code but it seems that it has an error. the error says that Uncaught typeError object# has no method 'HasScrollBar ' is there something wrong with the code? the HasScrollbar method is declared on top of the function but it seems that it cant find it please see code below

```
 $.fn.HasScrollBar = function () {
     //note: clientHeight= height of holder
     //scrollHeight= we have content till this height
     var _elm = $(this)[0];
     var _hasScrollBar = false;
     if ((_elm.clientHeight < _elm.scrollHeight) || 
         (_elm.clientWidth < _elm.scrollWidth)) {
         _hasScrollBar = true;
     }
     return _hasScrollBar;
 }

 function ab() {
     var a = $('td');
     $.each(a, function (i, data) {
         var check = data.HasScrollBar();
         if (check == true) {
             data.addClass('Overflow');
             data.attr('title', data.text());
         }
         data.attr('title', data.text());
         debugger;
     });

 };
 $('.Test').on('click', function () {

     ab();
 });
```

Comment: `Has scrollbar` != `HasScrollBar`

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It's very unlikely that the error says "has no method 'Has scrollbar'" unless you're calling it with `$('foo')[ 'Has scrollbar' ]`. It's important that you copy-paste the error message *exactly*, otherwise people get sidetracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of `$.each()` (in this case `data`) is a DOM element, not a jQuery object so it doesn't have jQuery methods. You need to do wrap it in a jQuery element first:

```
 $.each(a, function (i, data) {
     var $data = $( data );
     var check = $data.HasScrollBar();
     if (check == true) {
         $data.addClass('Overflow');
         $data.attr('title', $data.text());
     }
     $data.attr('title', $data.text());
 });
```

Comment: Would that not be solved using   var a = $('td');
     $a.each(function () {$
         var check = $(this).HasScrollBar();

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not need the counter, you can run .each on the collection

Also no need to add the title inside and outside of the if

```
$('td').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('Overflow',$this.HasScrollBar());
  $this.attr('title', $this.text());
});
```